# Is there a way to connect to another Spreadsheet and Allow access using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I'm using Spreadsheet and Apps Script to manage clients and billing.

To achieve this, I have a Spreadsheet containing all data and a Spreadsheet used as model that I duplicate for each project.

When creating the project (using Apps Script), I fill a cell with an IMPORTRANGE function.

The "problem" is that once the project is created and cells filled, I need to select the cell containing the IMPORTRANGE and "Allow access" to connect the other Spreadsheet.

Is there any way to ask the user to "Allow access" using Apps Script so the user won't have to do the step described before?

Edit:

```
=INDEX(
  IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEETID"; "SHEETNAME!$A:$A");
  match(L13;
    IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEETID"; "SHEETNAME!$B:$B");
  0)
)
```

I use IMPORTRANGE to display a cell in the other Spreadsheet based on a cell in the current Sheet. Using this method allows me to always have the cell up to date without having to restart the script.

Comment: No. But you can recreate the importrange functionality using scripts. You'd still need to authorize the script though

Comment: To my knowledge I can't really recreate the feature that uses IMPORTRANGE in my project.
Knowing that at the execution of the script I already ask a confirmation to the user, it is not a problem if at this moment it must also grant access. Do you think I can request access to the file when running the script (without actually using this access) to finally use the same technique as before (without having to allow access after)?
PS: I have updated the question with code and explainations

Comment: No. I don't think there's any way to prevent asking the user to "Allow access", while using the IMPORTRANGE function(unless may be if the source sheet is public). I believe you should use `getValues()` from another sheet and `setValues()` in this sheet instead.

Comment: Yes I could, but with this method the celle would not be always up to date. I mean, with the IMPORTRANGE function, I haven't to relaunch the script

Comment: There are lot of triggers. You can use the onEdit trigger or the clock trigger.

Comment: The onEdit trigger can't do the job as I don't want to wait for an edit to trigger the function. But the clock trigger can be the solution. I'll try with this. Thanks!